# Метод должен считывать текстовый файл в коллекцию HashMap

Tags: java

Этот метод должен считывать текстовый файл в коллекцию HashMap (словарь).
Ключем будет Дата и время записи, значением - Текст записи.
Вывести заполненную коллекцию HashMap в консоль. 
Проблема в том что перед выводом коллекции выводить null, а потом содержимое файла

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            HashMap<Date, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("Test.txt"),
                            "Cp1251")
            )) {
                String s;
                while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(hm.put(Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), s));
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открываем спецификацию на метод **put**:

*Returns:
the previous value associated with key, or null if there was no mapping for key. (A null return can also indicate that the map previously associated null with key.)*

Т.е. при вызове **put** возвращается либо предыдущее значение для этого ключа, либо null, если такого ключа не было (или ключ имел значение null). А т.к. коллекция создается с нуля, логично, что будет возвращаться null, т.к. предыдущих значений не было.

Почему бы не разделить запись в коллекцию и вывод в консоль?

```
System.out.println(s);
hm.put(Date.from(Instant.EPOCH), s);
```